# How to get softkeyboard height in float window correctly

Tags: android

Here I tried measure soft keyboard in full screen mode float window by add LayoutChangeListener to root view like this:

```
   mOnLayoutChangeListner = new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
            Rect r = getFrameVisiblePart();
            if (isMayBeKeyBoard(r)) {
                onKeyBoardShow(r.bottom, screenHeight - r.bottom);
            } else if (isKeyBoardMaybeHide(r)) {
                onKeyBoardHide();
            }
        }
    };
    mRootView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(mOnLayoutChangeListner);
```

getFrameVisiblePart:

```
 private Rect getFrameVisiblePart() {
    Rect r = new Rect();
    mRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
    return r;
}
```

And Here is Window Params:

```
Context context = App.getInstance();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) { 
        Point p = new Point();
        manager.getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(p);
        params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        params.height = (p.y > p.x ? p.y : p.x);
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
        ;
    } else {
        params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
        ;
    }
    params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR
```

Everythings works well. but it's can't click back and home button in NavigationBar.because of the type is SYSTEM_ERROR. I tried change type to TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT then the mesure function not work. onLayoutChange function invokes just when window first show and change view visibility of childView of Window and getFrameVisiblePart() function return visible area without expected